# Uploading Multiple Images from Flutter using PHP and changing file name

Tags: php

I am trying to upload multiple images and changing their names from images sent from flutter. Files are being uploaded without a problem, so the flutter side is not the problem, so I won't be attaching and code from the flutter side, the main problem is being unable to change the name for each individual file. Here is the code:

```
<?php
require 'dbh.php';

$image[] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmpFile[] = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


foreach($image as $keyImage => $value) {
    foreach($tmpFile as $key => $tmpFilevalue) {
        $fileExt = explode('.', $value);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
        $new_extension = 'jpg';
        $fileNameNew = "post".$key.".".$new_extension;
        
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilevalue, 'postImages/'. $fileNameNew)) {
           echo "ok";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

With this code above, I am only able to change the name of one image file, it seems that the loop is not increasing and staying in `0`. But if I do it this way, replacing the `$fileNameNew` to `$value` all files gets uploaded but the name does not change. Here is the code

```
<?php
    require 'dbh.php';
    
    $image[] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmpFile[] = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    
    
    foreach($image as $keyImage => $value) {
        foreach($tmpFile as $key => $tmpFilevalue) {
            $fileExt = explode('.', $value);
            $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
            $new_extension = 'jpg';
            $fileNameNew = "post".$key.".".$new_extension;
            
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilevalue, 'postImages/'. $value)) {
               echo "ok";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**$image** and **$tmpFile** are already an array.

instead of this :

```
$image[] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmpFile[] = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

try this :

```
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmpFile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work it gives me `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error

Answer (score 0):

You need to write loop like below:

```
if(!empty($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"])){ // check if valid array
  foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmpName) {
    $fileName=$_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];
    $fileTmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    ....
    ....
  }
}
```